# how to store some data in angularJs for later use?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have a simple Query. How can I store some data or value in angularJs for the later use? Let me be more clear: I want to store a value from one controller and use it in other controller?

Comment: You can use plain js cookies for that.

Comment: there is no way to do it angularJs ???why should i move to javascript again from angular

Comment: So use angularjs cookie methods there is an example here:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: @Soyaslan, cookies are overkill for just exchanging data between controllers because they will travel over the net as well.

Answer (score 2):

you should use angular service to achieve this. note that angular service is singleton which can be injected into controllers. a quick prototype to show the basic:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('myService', function () {
    var o = {x:1, y:2};
    return {
        getO: getO,
        setO: setO
    };

    function getO() {
        return o;
    }
    function setO(x, y) {
        o.x = x;
        o.y = y;
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrlA', function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.setO(3, 4);
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrlB', function ($scope, myService) {
    var o = myService.getO(); // {x:3, y:4}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a "service" in Angular terminology. For persisting data inside the service you can use wide variety of implementations from local storage to cloud json backend like firebase.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `$cacheFactory` if you do not need to refresh the page it will do the trick https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

So you can easily put and get stuffs from the cache wherever you want and whenever you need